# What are valid Identifiers for ISO14882 and ECMA335 standards?

Tags: c++, clr, standards, native

*The most beautiful about standards is that there are so many.* When reading the [C++11 standard](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail?csnumber=50372) compared to the [CLI-Standard (5th edition)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm), I'm getting a little bit confused about the identifier naming.

Where C++ allows according *[ISO/IEC 14882:2011 page 23]* ASCI: `_a-zA-Z0-9` (regardless the order) and according *[page 1249]* A lot of unicode characters .. there is no definition for `$` (0x24). On the other hand *[ECMA335 partition II page 13]* allows ``` a-zA-Z0-9_``@$ ``` as identifier-characters.

In other words C++ shouldn't support `$` (0x24) inside identifier names, but the CLR should. When testing this i've noticed exactly the opposite:

- native C++ ([native MSVC [of VS2010 Ultimate]](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us), [GCC [2.8.1]](http://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/), [minGW [latest]](http://www.mingw.org/)) supports `$`;
- C++\CLI or even C# (MSVC) doesn't support `$`.

So what is the truth? Am I missing something when reading the standards? Or is everybody doing what he wants to do?

Comment: Everything you've described details C++ not C#.  Remove the C# tag is this has nothing to do with C#

Comment: It has in context of that C# is a language implemented based on CLI.

Comment: Each language that implements CLI has different requirements for naming; if you question is about C++ identifiers, what C# does or does not do has nothing to do with C++ identifiers in or outside CLI.

Comment: As *CodeInChaos* wrote, I agree that a compiler doesn't need to fully implement the ECMA335 standard. The remaining problem is, why did all native C++-compilers (that I've tested) implement a feature that isn't part of the C++11 standard?

Comment: They all were implemented prior to C++11 and either haven't updated to C++11 or have chosen to remain backward compatible with their previous versions...

Comment: Okay - does this mean, that I can use for example `bla$blub` as identifier in my C++ programs and rely on this inconsistency? Or is it better to avoid it? (Regardless the beauty of the code.)

Comment: Rely on that only if you want to be bitten by any updates that make that C++ compiler implementation follow the standard. Personally, I'd avoid it.

Comment: Tested with GCC 2.8.1 regarding backwards compatibility.

Comment: @nemcija: backwards compatibility to prestandard c++ of 1998? I am just wondering why you tested a compiler that is not implementing the standard for question on how compilers implement the standard. Shouldnt you then have also tested msvc6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complication is that section 2.2 says:

> Physical source file characters are mapped, in an implementation-defined manner, to the basic source character set (introducing new-line characters for end-of-line indicators) if necessary. The set of physical source file characters accepted is implementation-defined.

So we formally don't know that the `$` in the source file corresponds to a dollar sign in the identifier. It just might be mapped to something else.

The requirements in the language standard is also a minimum what an implementation must provide. All compilers provide extensions to the standard language. Allowing extra characters in identifier names might be such an extension, possibly to support old pre-standard code or some OS specific features.

Comment: Okay in other words: **I should avoid it**, because it may ends up in undefined behaviour, depending on the compiler implementation, which is almost unknown.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why languages targeting the CLR should support all characters allowed in CLR identifiers. For example C# does not allow characters like `$` or `` ` ``, and uses some of them for compiler generated identifiers.

I'd expect a C++ implementation, no matter if it targets the CLR or normal assembly code to use the character set from the C++ specification.

Comment: I can confirm your first statement. But as I've tested it isn't like that. Native C++ shouldn't support it but it does. CLR C++ and C# may supports it but both doesn't.

Comment: Then it's a compiler extension (or bug depending on your PoV)

Comment: A bug that is common for almost all recommended (native) C++-compilers?

Comment: The C# specification does not allow `$` in identifiers.

Comment: Thats correct. I've also figured that out. But as written above the remaining part of my question is, why did all my tested native C++-Compilers support a feature that isn't supported according the C++11 standard?

Comment: @nemcija: where does the standard specify that the compilers are not allowed to support more than the minimal set of characters?